# FullCalendar dosen't automatically render the calendar (JQUERY wizard)?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to add  fullCalendar within an exsiting project [easyappointments](https://github.com/alextselegidis/easyappointments) , particulary in a file called ***book.php***.

When i charge the wizard it  displays just , the nav buttons :

[image]

however when i click in one of the nav buttons i get  to view the calendar .

what should i do to force the display of the calendar when the wizard charge  ?

this is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
                   

                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                                header: {
                                    left: 'prev,next today',
                                    center: 'title',
                                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                                },
                                defaultDate: '2019-11-20',
                                navLinks: true,
                                eventLimit: true,
                                events: [{
                                        title: 'Front-End Conference',
                                        start: '2019-11-16',
                                        end: '2019-11-18'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: 'Hair stylist with Mike',
                                        start: '2019-11-20',
                                        allDay: true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: 'Car mechanic',
                                        start: '2019-11-14T09:00:00',
                                        end: '2019-11-14T11:00:00'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: 'Dinner with Mike',
                                        start: '2019-11-21T19:00:00',
                                        end: '2019-11-21T22:00:00'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: 'Chillout',
                                        start: '2019-11-15',
                                        allDay: true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        title: 'Vacation',
                                        start: '2019-11-23',
                                        end: '2019-11-29'
                                    },
                                ]
                            });



 <div id="wizard-frame-2" class="wizard-frame" style="display:none;">
                <div class="frame-container" >

                    <div class="frame-groupe">
                        <div class="row" style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px;">
                            <b>Sélection de la date et de l'heure de l'activité INFO COLL</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" id="calendar-page" style="height: 10px; ">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div style="height: 10px; " id="calendar"><!-- Dynamically Generated Content --></div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


     
                <div class="modal-footer fixedFooter p-l-10 p-r-10">
                    <button type="button" id="button-back-2" class="btn button-back btn-secondary "data-step_index="2">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
                              <?= lang('back') ?>
                   </button>
                     <button type="button" id="button-next-2" class="btn button-next btn-primary" data-step_index="2">
                             <?= lang('next') ?>
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
                     </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem disappear when i put the calendar in the first wizard

## update

Easyappointment contains ,frontend_book.js, where Next step event is  programmed , i tried to change the code as below :

```
     /**
     * Event: Next Step Button "Clicked"
     *
     * This handler is triggered every time the user pressed the "next" button on the book wizard.
     * Some special tasks might be performed, depending the current wizard step.
     */
    $('.button-next').click(function () {
        // If we are on the first step and there is not provider selected do not continue
        // with the next step.
        if ($(this).attr('data-step_index') === '1' && $('#entreprise').val() =="" || $('#searchTextField').val()=="") {
            return;
        }
            
        // If we are on the 2nd tab then the user should have an appointment hour
        // selected.
        if ($(this).attr('data-step_index') === '2') {
        
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
        }
```

but that dosen't change anything !?

Comment: I don't have the resource handy at the moment, but I seem to recall reading that most jQuery plugins won't render on hidden elements. I suspect that's why your calendar doesn't load. Does your wizard have a "step changed" event that you can subscribe to?

Comment: @TiesonT. yes the project contains a file " frontend_book.js", where jquery  event ,such as click , actions are programmed.
but even changing that  click event function dosen't display the calendar in step 2

Comment: it may be the same  question , but the solution there didn't answer mine

Comment: I solved my question

Comment: Are you able to rephrase the question to show how it differs from the duplicate, and/or is your solution something that's likely to be applicable to, say, anyone using that "easyappointments" project? If so, your question can be flagged to be re-opened (you'd want to try to update your question first).

Comment: no it dosen't differs so much ,just the answer of that question is not very detailed:
calling ***.fullCalender('render')*** should be after calling the ***.show()*** function on the desired step , i added my answer there